# 422 Error Laravel ajax form post on Microsoft Edge

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, laravel

I have a form that posts some data to my laravel controller, it seems to work absolutely fine on Chrome, Safari and Firefox but fails with a 422 (unprocessable entity) error on Edge.

Could anyone see what might be the issue? I think it has something to do with the file being submitted in the request.

I previously had:

```
data: $(this).serialize(),
```

But that did not work with a file submission.

```
$.ajax({
                //global: false, //Stops global ajaxError handling from app/settings.js --}}
                type: "POST",
                url: "/admin/logs",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: new FormData(this),
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function (response) {
                    $('#loading').css({
                        display: "none"
                    });
                    toastr.options.onHidden = function() { window.location.href = '/admin/logs'; }
                    toastr.success(response.message);
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    $('#loading').css({
                        display: "none"
                    });
                }
            })
```

Thanks.

Comment: Did you look at what is being posed up that might break it?

Comment: posed up? What do you mean sorry?

Comment: Try `alert();` or `console.log();` with your data to see what is being send/posted,  just like @epascarello said. Post it here, so we can have some insight too. @Origin.

e.g. `succes: function (response) { alert(new Formdata(this)); // rest of current code },`

Comment: I seem to remember that IE (and possibly edge) serialize objects as [object Object] or something useless like that. Try to serialize with JSON.stringify(), I think that solved  similar problem for me at some point.

Comment: HTTP422: UNPROCESSABLE ENTITY - The request was well-formed but could not be processed due to semantic errors.
(XHR)POST - http://localhost:8000/admin/logs

Comment: @Origin like Rick suggests, please post the output of console.log(new FormData(this)). That will give us more information.

Comment: Alright, Whatexactly is the `new FormData(this)`? What does this exactly send, It might be possible Edge / IE understand the content but do not know how to process it due some small syntax errors. Could you look into the `/storage/laravel.log`? See if there are errors in there? Try `alert(new Formdata(this));` or `console.log(new Formdata(this));` but this time not in Edge/IE but firefox or chrome, it might output the data you're sending and not the error Edge/IE get. @Origin

Comment: @Rick_Jellema I tried that but I get an empty object on success/error, I'll check the laravel log now

Comment: So `Formdata(this)` is empty? What would you like to send with the ajax request? as in strings or images?

Comment: Okay so I logged to form output in the console when using data: $(this).serialize(), and got this: _token=BJZLa4eKk26PM93oteyZfZSLbFitw6AT7UVKa0Hl&property_ids%5B%5D=1&assigned_user_ids%5B%5D=5&log_type=Safety&log_severity=Important&log_title=Test%20Log&log_entry_content=sdfsdfdsff
(Note no file is being sent)

If i log with new FormData, I get an empty object

Comment: @Rick_Jellema just some strings with an optional file (image or pdf)

Comment: I see, do you serialize the form before you tried putting it into the object?
I think you may want to put the form data in the object before opening `$.ajax({})` so try this: `var formData = new Formdata(this);` and then `$.ajax({})` set `data: formData`. Might be worth a try. if you serialize the formdata beforehand, try it withouth serializing, since serializing removes the ability for an object to see what should be keys and value's.

Comment: @Rick_Jellema Same reponse: HTTP422: UNPROCESSABLE ENTITY - The request was well-formed but could not be processed due to semantic errors.
(XHR)POST - http://localhost:8000/admin/logs

Comment: Specify the `contentType: false,` as `contentType: "json",`? and then try `data: $(this).serializeArray(),`? or `$(this).serialize(),`?

Comment: Interesting development, it seems to work fine with smaller files. Tried it with a 576kb file and it worked... Then i try a 3.51MB file and it fails...

Comment: Have you set up the upload size correctly on your environment? Or you don't have any validation that might conflict with the size ?

Comment: @Rick_Jellema I have a 10MB validation rule, and it's weird that it's only edge having the problem?

Comment: Hm, Could you show me the form where you send the data from to the ajax request? @Origin

Comment: @Rick_Jellema https://pastebin.com/a4YzrxY7 Here's the whole form/js

Comment: try adding `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your `<form>` tag, then try it again?

Comment: @Rick_Jellema Still no joy, it must be an issue with file size as it doesn't appear to be working on chrome now... a 970KB PDF failes to upload, yet a 16kb PDF was okay, not sure what's going on

Comment: I'm at a loss, Let me get back to you with this issue in a couple of hours, gotta get to work; Meanwhile try to do some google searches on the HTTP 422, e.g. __HTTP 422 Filesizes__. And take a look into the stacktraces of the laravel.log file. in `storage/logs/laravel.log`

Comment: Oh and install firebug if you don't have it already, it's a nice extension for chrome/firefox for JS debugging.

Comment: @Rick_Jellema No problem, i'll keep trying, thanks for the help

Comment: @Origin Try increasing the PHP Memory in your php.ini settings.  I read on [laracast](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/422-unprocessable-entity-when-upload-an-image) that it might cause the http 422.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, it seems to be fixed. It was a mixture of Edge being difficult, max file size/max post size, the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` as @Rick_Jellema said seemed to help accept the correct mime types from the file on Edge. I didn't end up changing the initial ajax submission or the validation on the server. Thanks guys

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

> 422 (unprocessable entity)

This is how Laravel shows validation error in ajax requests.
You can extract data from that response and show the error message if needed.
Try after removing validation rules to confirm.

check the official [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation)

Comment: So i removed validation rules and tried, i get this error: HTTP500: SERVER ERROR - The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.
(XHR)POST - http://localhost:8000/admin/logs

The file appears to be empty as well

Comment: What file is empty? What do the logs say? Check `storage/laravel/laravel.log` and/or your Apache and/or your PHP logs.  You are driving blind if you're not looking at the logs.

Comment: goto network tab in the console and try again, there you can see the request and can see the error on clicking on the request

Comment: @Don'tPanic I've checked the log but nothing helped in there for this matter. I think its a file size/mime type issue

Comment: @Origin 422 is Laravel's standard validation failure response for an AJAX request https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation.  If you remove your validation, and still get a 500 error, you have either a problem in validation **and** another problem, or the 2 problems are related.  The logs should help you find out which of those it is, and what it is.  Maybe your 500 is unrelated, but even if that's true you're going to hit it as soon as you solve the validation issue :-)

Comment: @Don'tPanic I'll keep plugging away, thanks for the advice